# Appending element jquery?

Tags: jquery, append

heres a link to the web page s1527.mtchs.org/chat.html
When you submit or hit enter, the value of my textarea is appended to a div. when this happens again, the old value in the div is deleted and appended with the new one? how do I make it so it adds another value instead of deleting the old one?

jQuery:

```
var captionLength = 0;
var caption = "";

$(document).ready(function()
{
  setInterval ( "cursorAnimation()", 600 );
});

function testTypingEffect()
{ 
if(userInput.value !== "Message")
{
  caption = $("textarea#userInput").val();
  $(caption).append('<div id = content></div>');
  type();
  }
}

function type() 
{
    $('p.caption').html(caption.substr(0, captionLength++));
    if(captionLength < caption.length+1)
    {
        setTimeout("type()", 50);
    }
    else {
        captionLength = 0;
        caption = "";
}   
}
function testErasingEffect()
{
 caption = $("p.caption").html();
  captionLength = caption.length;
 if (captionLength>0)
  {
erase();
 }
 else
  {
$('p.caption').html("You didn't write anything to erase, but ok!");
   setTimeout("testErasingEffect()", 1000);
 }
   }

           function erase()
          {
$('p.caption').html(caption.substr(0, captionLength--));
if(captionLength >= 0)
{
    setTimeout("erase()", 50);
}
else {
    captionLength = 0;
    caption = "";
}   
}

function cursorAnimation() 
{
  $("p.cursor").animate(
 {
   opacity: 0
}, 300, "swing").animate(
 {
 opacity: 1
 }, 300, "swing");
}
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
   if(e.which == 13) {
       testTypingEffect();
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="chatwrapper">
  <div id="tab">chatname</div>
  <div id="content">
    <p id="time"> 2:14:26pm</p>
    <div id="effectTesting">
      <p id="user">\\diablo\\student\2015:</p>
      <p class="caption"></p>
      <p class="cursor">|</p>
    </div>
    <p class="testing"></p>
    <br>
  </div>
  <div id="textarea">
    <textarea id="userInput" onclick="if(this.value=='Message'){this.value=''}" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Message'}">Message</textarea>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="testTypingEffect()"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used .html() instead of .append() on line 21. Changing this was not enough because your dealing with the actual caption length and how to type out the string was not proper so I redid your key functions. See my jsfiddle. I also made it so it adds new content on a new line each time submit is pressed. Also, the cursor will "follow" the content!

See: http://jsfiddle.net/GJBGt/9/

HTML:
 Your original HTML

CSS:

```
span{ float:left; clear:both; margin: 5px 0px; overflow: auto;}
#textarea{ float: left; clear:both}
.cursor{ display:inline }
```

JS:

```
var caption = "";
//you REALLY DON'T NEED variable captionLength that you had here before

$(document).ready(function()
{
  setInterval ( "cursorAnimation()", 600 );
});

function testTypingEffect()
{ 
if(userInput.value !== "Message")
{
  caption = $("textarea#userInput").val();

  typefirst();
  }
}

function typefirst() 
{
    $('p.caption').append("<span></span>");
    type();
}

function type()
{
    $("span").eq(-1).append(caption.substr(0, 1));
    $(".cursor").appendTo($("span").eq(-1));
    if(caption.length > 0)
    {
        caption = caption.substring(1);
        setTimeout("type()", 50);
    }
    else {
        caption = "";
}
```

Comment: it doesn't put new chat on a separate line, just appends it to the existing text, but at least it solves the problem and you can now append to the chat. You can easily make it so new messages go on new lines instead of just get lumped to existing text. If you need help with that comment here.

Comment: I helped you with that too and have solution for putting each new chat content on a new line, I updated my solution

Comment: well it's not 100% perfect, the cursor doesn't follow the text (that can be done though too) but it's a good starting point and you get the idea right? I hope this helps.

Comment: Got really good news for you - here's how to make the cursor "follow" the text - using this jsfiddle: -->  http://jsfiddle.net/GJBGt/8/ you see that just two small changes: 1) displaying the cursor as "inline" css, and 2) in the JS one additional line always moving the cursor to the end of the new line in the chat while it's typing --> will make a nice typing effect where the cursor even follows the typing - I updated my answer again :D

Comment: It works! any personal suggestions? s1527.mtchs.org/chat.html

i'm gonna implement jquery and ajax and php to actually make it work, for now though just css jquery and html. Thanks so much!

One last thing, I want to have it so when it appends, the date, name, and colon are to the left so it looks like this:

9:52pm user : messagetext?

Comment: oh no! if you type too much, when you reach the end of the content box, it goes out because it doesn't actually put an element on the page. Help?!?

Comment: last problem. if you type something and click several times, it cuts off the typing from the second time you hit submit. how can you make the textarea empty after submission?

Comment: To really guarantee that someone doesn't interrupt a current "typing out" of the chat, you got to have some sort of queue solution that knows if there's something still going on. For your demo purposes, emptying it out should be enough (for you, turning it to the word "Message" is the good idea) using this line in the testTypingEffect function: $("textarea#userInput").val('Message'); should work. The reason this is OK is because you have your variable "caption" that takes care of it so yes you can safely empty your input box. I have updated working jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/GJBGt/10/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure how you want it to look like in the end, but you're using append() wrong.

Try this:

```
$("#content").append("<p class='caption'>"+caption+"</p>");
```

Instead of your:

```
$(caption).append('<div id = content></div>');
```

This will add the element `<p class="caption">(textarea caption)</p>` into the .

You may also want to change your type() animation a bit, something like this:

```
$('p.caption:last').html(caption.substr(0, captionLength++));
```

Instead of your:

```
$('p.caption').html(caption.substr(0, captionLength++));
```

This is still not perfect since the cursor is not at the bottom, but you can achieve that by appending the new element right above the cursor.

Comment: Im a bit confused, but I think you have the concept. What I want to do, is the user input in the textarea to be appended into the content div on submitting, it does that, but when you add another one have it add on instead of replacing the old value in the div. like a chat box.